# Azure PowerShell script to compare files in the blob with local destination and download files which is not available in the destination

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

Could you please help me with Azure PowerShell script to compare files in the blob with local destination and download files which is not available in the destination.

I tried some, but able to get the answer.

```
$blobNames = Get-Content 
    
 For ($i=0; $i -lt $blobNames.Length; $i++) {
     $blob = $blobNames[$i]
     Write-Host "Downloading $blob. Please wait."
     Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob -Container $containerName -Destination $destination -Context $context -Verbos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PowerShell script to compare files in the blob with local destination and download files which is not available in the destination:

I've created a script and it works for me:

```
$ContainerName ='<containername>'
$destination_path = 'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\blobcheck' #pathtobedownloaded
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext '<storageaccount>' -StorageAccountKey 'accesskey'
$Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Ctx
$localfile = get-childitem -LiteralPath C:\Users\xxxxxx
For ($i=0; $i -lt $Blobs.Length; $i++) {
     if($Blobs[$i].Name -eq $localfile){
     Write-Host "Presented"
     }
     else{
     $blob = $Blobs[$i].Name
     Write-Host "Downloading $blob. Please wait."
     Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Blob $blob -Container $ContainerName -Destination $destination_path -Context $Ctx -Verbose
     }
     
}
```

***Compared and downloaded the files which is not present in my local folder:***

[image]

***Files uploaded in My Local folder (destination_path):***

[image]

***Prompting to rewrite if the file is already exists as shown below:***

[image]

*If the prompt is not needed, then you can simply use*
`DisplayAlerts = FALSE`

Note: *Get storage access key from Azure Portal:*

Goto `<Storageaccount> -> Access keys`

[image]